# Using RabbitMQ to capture web application log

Tags: iis, logging, rabbitmq

I'm trying to setup RabbitMQ to take web application logs to a log server.

My log server will listen to one channel and store the logs that comes in.
There are several web applications that need to send info to the log server.

With many connections (users) hitting the web server, what is the best design to publish messages to RabbitMQ without locking each other?  Is it a good idea to keep opening a new connection to the MQ for each web request?  Is there some sort of message queue pool?

I'm using IIS for a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you’re leveraging the .NET framework to build your application, given that it’s hosted in IIS. If so, you can also leverage [Daishi.AMQP](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.AMQP), which has a built-in `QueuePool` feature. [Here](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/07/31/microservices-in-c-part-2-consistent-message-delivery/) is a tutorial that outlines the mechanism in full.

To answer your question, you should initially establish a connection to RabbitMQ from your application server. You can then initialise a Channel (a process that executes within the context of the underlying connection) to serve each HTTP request. It is not a good idea to establish a new connection for each request.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ has a build in queue feature. It is well documented, have a look at the official docs: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html